# Send notification mail using Cloudformation template when Codebuild is failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

I am having an existing Cloudformation template to create a Codebuild, and I want to send a notification mail by updating the template when make a Codebuild fails. How to make a change in such a way ?

I'm completely new to Cloudformation, and it would be better if I get some inputs regarding the same. Thanks!

Comment: CloudFormation is not used for sending emails. SNS or SES are used instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly. You want to update the cloud formation template if the build fails on codebuild.

You can get notified from codebuild by creating a notification rule on build failures.It will send messages to SNS. This message can be consumed with lambda to update the cloud formation template. There are many
ways as notification to SNS can be consumed.
More information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rengas.
My requirement is like I need to update my cloudformation template, there I can provide mail id like whom the notification should be sent.
I tried creating a notification rule as you mentioned above, and I couldn't find a place to mention the mail id. 
Could you please confirm ?

Comment: @Kivi It has to be done at SNS. You need to create a topic in SNS
Then you choose email as the option and configure there.
You can read the SNS documentation on how to go about doing it

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SNS topic in AWS for the notifications regarding the codebuild/codepipeline triggers. you can also manage what will trigger the SNS to send the email ( such as build fail/success, etc).

Please refer this AWS document for your reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html